# Watch nest handlebar partial files change

Tags: typescript, nestjs, tsc

[Nest](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/mvc#model-view-controller) with [Handlebars](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/partials.html) as view engine, is there a way to configure which folder to watch for changes. Default watch is based on `tsc`.

Every time I created or edited a partial `hbs` file, the progressive compilation is not triggered. I used `nest start --watch` for development.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution written down in [hbs package](https://github.com/pillarjs/hbs#readme) README page at the bottom.

A package [hbs-utils](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hbs-utils)

Will save me a lot of time if Nest can mention it in their docs together when they talked about using `hbs`